# ES6 Promises Error Handling

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm currently reading "YKDJS - Async & Performance" by Kyle Simpson, in particular Chapter 3 - Promises.

The author says that any Promise for which no rejection handler is registered receives a default one:

```
let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve("Yay!"); });
p.then(
function(val) { /* Do whatever */ } 
   /* Default rejection handler
   , function(e) { throw e; } */
);
```

Later in the chapter he claims that one problem with the way `Promise`s are designed is the following:

In any `Promise` chain, any error that happens in one of the handler functions of the last `Promise` in the chain is just "swallowed" instead of being reported.
He proposes to change the way `Promise`s work so that any `Promise` that doesn't have a rejection handler reports the error by throwing a global error. Then he proposes a theoretical `Promise#defer()` function one could use on a `Promise` to prevent this reporting behavior.

Now my question is: How do these two go together? It's true that any `Promise`that doesn't have a rejection handler receives a default one which just throws the rejection value as a global error:

```
Promise.reject("Oops");
/* VM668:1 Uncaught (in promise) Oops */
```

So already `Promise`s seem to work in just the way he proposes. 
Am I misunderstanding something? Thanks for any help.

Comment: good article. helps to understand promises.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies

Comment: @VasylGutnyk How does that answer the question?

Comment: @Bergi u can find there info-examples about error handling.

Comment: @Bergi Vasyl posted it as a comment, not an answer. The information that they linked to may help OP understand Promises a little better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [*Uncaught Handling* he mentions](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch3.md#uncaught-handling) in

> Some Promise libraries have added methods for registering something
>   like a "global unhandled rejection" handler, which would be called
>   instead of a globally thrown error. But their solution for how to
>   identify an error as "uncaught" is to have an arbitrary-length timer,
>   say 3 seconds, running from time of rejection. If a Promise is
>   rejected but no error handler is registered before the timer fires,
>   then it's assumed that you won't ever be registering a handler, so
>   it's "uncaught."
>
> In practice, this has worked well for many libraries, as most usage
>   patterns don't typically call for significant delay between Promise
>   rejection and observation of that rejection.

has been standardised as [*unhandled rejection* warnings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PromiseRejectionEvent) (not using an arbitrary timer, but firing right away). It does indeed work quite well.

He also states in [Chapter 4 of *ES6 & Beyond*](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch4.md)

> [When] we are not listening for that rejection, […] it will be
>   silently held onto for future observation. If you never observe it by
>   calling a `then(..)` or `catch(..)`, then it will go unhandled. Some
>   browser developer consoles may detect these unhandled rejections and
>   report them, but this is not reliably guaranteed; you should always
>   observe promise rejections.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!